# Adobe Edge Animation Mouse Wheel Smooth Scroll

Tags: animation, scroll, mousewheel, smoothing, adobe-edge

I have made parallax scrolling by using Adobe Edge Animation there is a problem with scroll by mouse wheel. How can i make it smooth.

http://bestbuypakistan.com/Oil/Oil.html

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like your animations stall every few pixels as you're scrolling. This is simply in the fluid motion of the animation.

You'll need to redo the keyframing for the animations and it seems like you're using x and y to animate the motions. Try using motion paths instead to get a more fluid and slick feel to the effect.

I know this isn't much of an answer, but I hope I was able to help in some way! :)

Cheers!